# SQL Select all records where unique composite key

Tags: sql, select

Example table:

```
foo bar baz gif xyz
--- --- --- --- ---
me  my  at  bb  cc
me  my  at  aa  zz
qq  33  er  tt  oo
22  jj  pp  ww  mm
```

I need a SQL that returns the unique records for fields "foo, bar, baz".
In this example, three of the four records should be returned:

```
me, my, at, bb, cc
qq, 33, er, tt, oo
22, jj, pp, ww, mm
```

Comment: What makes you choose bb and cc? Does it matter if you get aa and cc? is there another column eg ID or datetime that gives precedence?

Comment: Generally speaking it is an invalid task for SQL since your first row is ambigious and you are not saying how to determine which row to take - the one ending with `bb, cc` or another one with `aa, zz` at the end. In your sample you've selected `bb, cc` due to some reason (order?), but SQL doesn't have an `order` for rows until you specify `order by`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absence of any rules for gif and xyz, this will take the lowest values of each

```
SELECT
   foo, bar, baz, MIN(gif), MIN(xyz)
FROM
   MyTable
GROUP BY
   foo, bar, baz
```

Comment: this will return the three records only?

Comment: @bmw0128: yes, it's an aggregate- However, check the comments on your question for how to choose gif and xyz

Comment: i now see what you mean, i just want to know if the combo exists, so I do not care about gif and xyz...so if your solution will only bring back unique combo values, that's what i need

Comment: Well it will not isolate 'the row' just the minimum values for the other columns - you would not get the output that you stated you needed

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said which version of SQL this is.....?

In sql server 2005 or greater this is a ROW_NUMBER() function that will let you select the *first* row (ordered by whatever predicate you provide)

The query would look like

```
SELECT
    [foo]
    , [bar]
    , [baz]
    , [gif]
    , [xyz]
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        [foo]
        , [bar]
        , [baz]
        , [gif]
        , [xyz]
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY [foo], [bar], [baz]
            ORDER BY [gif] DESC, [xyz] DESC
            )
            AS [rnk]
    FROM
        <TheTable>
    )
WHERE
    [rnk] = 1
```

I believe there is a similar function (they are called windowing functions) in Oracle. I don't know about mysql

Answer (score 0):

Not much to it, really:

```
select *
from myTable t1
join ( select distinct foo,bar,baz
       from myTable
     ) t2 on t2.foo = t1.foo
         and t2.bar = t1.bar
         and t2.baz = t1.baz
```